# Convolution sum of divisor functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples, equidistribution

Let $\sigma_0(n)$ be the divisor counting function
$$\sigma_0(n) = \sum_{d \vert n} 1.$$
I'm interested in the convolution sum
$$ S(n) := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sigma_0(k) \sigma_0(n-k)$$
I ran some quick numerical experiments and it looks like for odd primes $p$, the convolution sum $S(n)$ is equidistributed* mod $p$:
$$\lim_{X \to \infty} \dfrac{\lvert  \{  n<X: S(n) \equiv a \mod p  \}  \rvert}{X} = \dfrac{1}{p}.$$
Is this true? And if so, could anyone sketch a proof / provide a reference?

---

*This is a bit of a lie. In fact, the data seems to suggest that certain residue classes occur more often than others, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444371/is-the-divisor-counting-function-equidistributed-mod-p). But I've stated my observation in this (incorrect) way to avoid making the question too long. In any case, I'd like to learn of any techniques I could use to get a handle of $S(n)$ mod $p$.

Comment: You probably want to use additive characters mod  here instead of multiplicative characters. Do you mind saying a bit about your motivation for asking this question? Is it just curiosity, or did it arise from some other considerations?

Comment: Sure, here's my motivation: I'm studying a product of two Eisenstein series. The Fourier coefficients of Eisenstein series are divisor functions, and it turns out the Fourier coefficients of the product of Eisenstein series is a convolution of divisor functions. I'm interested in how the Fourier coefficients of this product of Eisenstein series are distributed mod $p$, which leads me to ask how this convolution of divisor sums is distributed mod $p$.

Comment: This definition apparently involves $\sigma_0(0)$. Is that right?

Comment: @colt_browning Nope, I don't think it involves $\sigma_0(0)$. The summation over $k$ in the definition of $S(n)$ is for $k=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: @AdithyaChakravarthy Yes, and the 2nd factor is $\sigma_0(n-k)$, which becomes $\sigma_0(0)$ for $k=n$.

Comment: @colt_browning Thanks for catching that - I fixed it so that $k$ runs from $k=1, \dots, n-1$.

Comment: The relevant OEIS entry is https://oeis.org/A055507 , but the references there are apparently mostly about asymptotic properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

Maybe this helps though it has $\sigma(n)=\sigma_1(n)$ not $\sigma_0(n)$. It may be that a similar identity may hold for $\sigma_0(n).$ In a long paper [available here](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/math-2022-0038/html) we find

> the  convolution sum of the divisor function:
> $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sigma_1(k)\sigma_1(n-k),$
> which was presented by Besge [1](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/math-2022-0038/html). After that, convolution sums for such divisor functions have become the subject of interest to many mathematicians.

According to this [paper](https://koreascience.kr/article/JAKO201514039404948.pdf) the sum evaluated by Besge satisfies
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sigma_1(k)\sigma_1(n-k)=\frac{5}{12}\sigma_3(n)+\left(\frac{1}{12}-\frac{n}{2} \right)\sigma_1(n)
$$

There is much more in that first paper I linked to that may be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED ANSWER. I'm now quite sure that this is true for every odd prime $p$. Using the list available on the OEIS (A055507), it appears that when you perform a $\chi^2$ test, for each prime $p=3,5,7,13,17,19,23,29$ and $31$, the finite sequence $\{S(n): n\le10000\}$ is uniformly distributed on $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$. The $p$-values are always largely above $.05$. In particular there is a quite strong statistical evidence that there are no congruence classes that appear significantly more often than others.

However, the same analysis for the prime $11$ surprisingly returns a $p$-value $p=0.005$, but as, H. Cohen remarked (see comment below), this apparent non-uniformity disappears, when one considers $n\le 10^7$.

[image]

Comment: I performed furhter analyses and I found that equidistribution holds for all $p\le109$ (the greatest I tested), except the case $p=97$ for which the $p$-value is .008.

Comment: You are correct up to 10000: a=5 mod 11 occurs much less than the others (826 compared to an average of 909, and a=9 and a=10 also are small). However if you go further (I went to $10^7$) this disappears. Law of small numbers I guess.

Comment: Quite interesting how it takes a while for equidistribution to appear. I still have very little idea how to prove this, but thanks for the data.